# Running secured and non secured websites on the same IIS7 server

Tags: ssl, iis-7

We have a single IIS7 web server serving multiple websites. All the sites have different domain names. One site (I'll call it securedsite.com) is an ecommerce website so we have a SSL certificate for that site.

If a user types https://someothersite.com the server routes the request to https://securedsite.com instead of the original domain.

How do I have the server ignore https for sites that are not secured with a SSL certificate?

Answer (score 0):

You could put a host name in the site binding for both websites. This would ensure only the correct traffic goes to the correct site.